# error when trying class with linked list c++

Tags: c++, list, iterator

I am trying out simple class and linked list implementation.
Please help me out with this code as i am receiving 
"list iterator not dereferencable"
when running the code.
Thanks

```
#include<iostream>
#include<list>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

class Car
{
public:
    void getType(string x)
    {
        type = x;
    }

    string showType()
    {
        return type;
    }

private:
    string type;
};

void main()
{
    string p;
    list<Car> c;
    list<Car>::iterator curr = c.begin();

    cout << "Please key in anything you want: ";
    getline(cin, p);
    curr->getType(p);

    cout << "The phrase you have typed is: " << curr->showType() << endl;

}
```

Comment: there is nothing in your list so `curr` doesn't point to a valid `Car`, you need to add a Car to your list

Comment: A setter named `getType()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write the following way

```
cout << "Please key in anything you want: ";
getline(cin, p);

c.push_back( Car() );

list<Car>::iterator curr = c.begin();

curr->getType(p);
```

And it is much better to rename the member function `getType` to `setType`.:)

Take into account that the function main without parameters shall be declared like

```
int main()
^^^
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't insert anything into your `list`. So the iterator is not valid, it's pointing to `c.end()` and dereferencing it is undefined behaviour.

Instead add a `Car` to your `list` before you get the `begin` iterator.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<list>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

class Car
{
public:
    void setType(const string& x)
    {
        type = x;
    }

    string showType()
    {
        return type;
    }

private:
    string type;
};

int main()
{
    string p;
    list<Car> c;   

    c.push_back(Car{});
    auto curr = c.begin();

    cout << "Please key in anything you want: ";
    getline(cin, p);
    curr->setType(p);

    cout << "The phrase you have typed is: " << curr->showType() << endl;
}
```